# User issues when opening the owssvr Exporting a List to Excel

Tags: excel, export

I have created a List and Exported that list to Excel via owssvr. I have one User in our 15 person group that when she opens the owssver. One of the columns is supposed to show Last Name, First Name. However it is showing, "Object, Content Type". For all other users in the group it is displaying the Last, first, as shown in the actual SharePoint List. I have verified her permissions are set up correctly. Is this a Sharepoint issue or possibly an Excel problem?

Comment: Close the browser and exit Excel 2013 then try it again. It might be due to connection with the Excel & SharePoint

Comment: We tried a system restart. It didn't work. The odd thing is the process was working fine last week.

Comment: What exactly does the user open? An existing Excel file with a data connection? Do the others open EXACTLY the same file, or does she have her own copy?  What happens if she navigates to the list view and opens that in Excel?

Comment: She's opening the same files as all others the owssvr. When she clickks, "Open in browser" mode. It shows the normal SharePoint list.

Answer (score 0):

We decided just to create a saved copy of the excel with the data connection to SharePoint. I think the problem lies within her network profile. Thanks for the help folks!